# What are the benefit of assigning function results to variables vs calling inline?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm learning Firebase. In many code examples I see something like this:

```
const auth = getAuth();

await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
```

while in firebase web codelab they call `getAuth` directly:

```
await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), provider);
```

same thing with `getFirestore`.
so which one is the correct way of doing it and if they are both the same what is the better practice?

edit: when I need to use `auth` object more than once will I get any performance benefits by calling `getAuth` once and assigning it to a variable?

Comment: There are a couple of correct answers but generally, those two code snippets behave 'the same'. HOWEVER, more context is needed; technically this `const auth = getAuth();` will occupy memory and depending on where it's placed it could stay in memory. Whereas this `await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), provider);` may be used once and disposed of. Again, depending on placement in code. If you're going to re-use the var in several places, this `const auth = getAuth();` is convenient as it will maintain a value and won't have be populated again. So, they are 'the same'.. kinda. No performance diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to reuse the auth variable, then you can simply call it directly.

It doesn't have any significant difference in this case.

Comment: so if I need to reuse auth variable it is better to assign `getAuth` returned value to `auth`?

Comment: yes.. this way you avoid making the function call multiple times :)

Answer (score 2):

These two code examples are functionally the same. The first example is simply more verbose.

Comment: calling once should be same. do I get any performance benefits when I need `auth` object more than once by calling `getAuth` once and assigning it to `auth` variable?

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between those two approaches. If you want to use the result that is returned by `getAuth()`, only once, it makes sense to use it like this:

```
await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), provider);
```

Otherwise, save it to the `auth` variable and use it as many times as you want. In terms of performance, there is no difference at all.